# Identifying the second lowest and second highest value in Java

Tags: java, sorting

This is not only working when you input two or more same value, it will make the output all zero instead of giving the same result as first highest and second highest. Also we can't use array and arraysort or any sorting function.

For example if I input 4 4 2 2 1, it will make all the result 0 instead of giving:

```
first highest: 4
second highest:4
second lowest :2
first lowest :1
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pres {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
    int fh = 0, sh = 0, sl = 0, fl = 0;
    int a = s.nextInt();
    int b = s.nextInt();
    int c = s.nextInt();
    int d = s.nextInt();
    int e = s.nextInt();
    if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e) {
        fl = a;
    }  if (b < a && b < c && b < d && b < e) {
        fl = b;
    }  if (c < a && c < b && c < d && c < e) {
        fl = c;
    }  if (d < a && d < b && d < c && d < e) {
        fl = d;
    }  if (e < a && e < b && e < c && e < d) {
        fl = e;
    }
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e) {
        fh = a;
    }  if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b > e) {
        fh = b;
    }  if (c > a && c > b && c > d && c > e) {
        fh = c;
    }  if (d > a && d > b && d > c && d > e) {
        fh = d;
    }  if (e > a && e > b && e > c && e > d) {
        fh = e;
    }
    //sh
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a < e) {
        sh = a;
    }  if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a < e) {
        sh = a;
    }  if (a < b && a > c && a > d && a > e) {
        sh = a;
    }  if (a > b && a < c && a > d && a > e) {
        sh = a;
    }  if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a > e) {
        sh = a;
    }
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b < e) {
        sh = a;
    }  if (b > a && b > c && b > d && b < e) {
        sh = b;
    }  if (b < a && b > c && b > d && b > e) {
        sh = b;
    }  if (b > a && b < c && b > d && b > e) {
        sh = b;
    }  if (b > a && b > c && b < d && b > e) {
        sh = b;
    }
    if (c > b && c > a && c > d && c < e) {
        sh = c;
    }  if (c > b && c > a && c > d && c < e) {
        sh = c;
    }  if (c < b && c > a && c > d && c > e) {
        sh = c;
    }  if (c > b && c < a && c > d && c > e) {
        sh = c;
    }  if (c > b && c > a && c < d && c > e) {
        sh = c;
    }
    if (d > b && d > c && d > a && d < e) {
        sh = d;
    }  if (d > b && d > c && d > a && d < e) {
        sh = d;
    }  if (d < b && d > c && d > a && d > e) {
        sh = d;
    }  if (d > b && d < c && d > a && d > e) {
        sh = d;
    }  if (d > b && d > c && d < a && d > e) {
        sh = d;
    }
    if (e > b && e > c && e > d && e < a) {
        sh = e;
    }  if (e > b && e > c && e > d && e < a) {
        sh = e;
    }  if (e < b && e > c && e > d && e > a) {
        sh = e;
    }  if (e > b && e < c && e > d && e > a) {
        sh = e;
    }  if (e > b && e > c && e < d && e > a) {
        sh = e;
    }
    //sl
    if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a > e) {
        sl = a;
    }  if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a < e) {
        sl = a;
    }  if (a < b && a > c && a > d && a > e) {
        sl = a;
    }  if (a > b && a < c && a > d && a > e) {
        sl = a;
    }  if (a > b && a > c && a < d && a > e) {
        sl = a;
    }
    if (b < a && b < c && b < d && b > e) {
        sl = a;
    }  if (b < a && b < c && b < d && b > e) {
        sl = b;
    }  if (b > a && b < c && b < d && b < e) {
        sl = b;
    }  if (b < a && b > c && b < d && b < e) {
        sl = b;
    }  if (b < a && b < c && b > d && b < e) {
        sl = b;
    }
    if (c < b && c < a && c < d && c > e) {
        sl = c;
    }  if (c < b && c < a && c < d && c > e) {
        sl = c;
    }  if (c > b && c < a && c < d && c < e) {
        sl = c;
    }  if (c < b && c > a && c < d && c < e) {
        sl = c;
    }  if (c < b && c < a && c > d && c < e) {
        sl = c;
    }
    if (d < b && d < c && d < a && d > e) {
        sl = d;
    }  if (d < b && d < c && d < a && d > e) {
        sl = d;
    }  if (d > b && d < c && d < a && d < e) {
        sl = d;
    }  if (d < b && d > c && d < a && d < e) {
        sl = d;
    }  if (d < b && d < c && d > a && d < e) {
        sh = d;
    }
    if (e < b && e < c && e < d && e > a) {
        sl = e;
    }  if (e < b && e < c && e < d && e > a) {
        sl = e;
    }  if (e > b && e < c && e < d && e < a) {
        sl = e;
    }  if (e < b && e > c && e < d && e < a) {
        sl = e;
    }  if (e < b && e < c && e > d && e < a) {
        sl = e;
    }
    if (a < fl) {
        sh = fl;
        fl = a;
    }
    if ((a > fl) && (a < sl)) {
        sl = a;
    }
    if (b < fl) {
        sl = fl;
        fl = b;
    }
    if ((b > fl) && (b < sl)) {
        sl = b;
    }
    if (c < fl) {
        sh = fl;
        fl = c;
    }
    if ((c > fl) && (c < sl)) {
        sh = c;
    }
    if (d < fl) {
        sl = fl;
        fl = d;
    }
    if ((d > fl) && (d < sl)) {
        sl = d;
    }
    if (e < fl) {
        sl = fl;
        fl = e;
    }
    if ((e > fl) && (e < sl)) {
        sl = e;
    }
    else
    fh = sh;
    fl = sh;
    sl = sh;
    sh = fl;


    System.out.println("First highest  :" + fh);
    System.out.println("Second highest :" + sh);
    System.out.println("First lowest   :" + fl);
    System.out.println("Second lowest  :" + sl);
```

Comment: Though i have upvoted for your effort, this is too much code to solve a simple problem. Look at using `loops` and simple data structures to solve it efficiently.

Comment: Put the values into an array, sort them, then the values you need will be in positions `0`, `1`, `n-2` and `n-1`, where `n` is the length of the array. Or use something like `Collections.sort()` if it's not forbidden. There's absolutely no need for that huge mess of unreadable `if` statements. You also potentially have a bug with your last `else` statement, because you didn't use curly brackets, meaning the `else` consists only of `fl = sh;`.

Comment: If the input is `4-4-2-2-1` you will never get a proper output, since you just check for lower or higher and ignore the equal, in addition you seem to have several logic flaws.

Comment: It seems very Monty Python-esque to be set this task and then forbidden to use any of the appropriate tools and data structures that would make this straightforward. I'm struggling to see what they're trying to teach you by imposing these limitations.

Answer (score 1):

This code is by far to complex for this kind of problem. Try to keep things shorter to simplify things - this will also make debugging a lot easier:

```
int[] inp = new int[5];

//read input into array here

//here we have two options: 
//either use the javaAPI to sort the array:
Arrays.sort(inp);

int min2 = inp[1];//second smallest element
int max2 = inp[3];//second highest element

//search for the value on your own:
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//searching for a minimum -> greatest possible value
int min2 = min;

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max2 = max;

for(int i : inp){
    if(i < min){
        min2 = min;
        min = i;
    }else if(i < min2){
        min2 = i;
    }

    if(i > max){
        max2 = max;
        max = i;
    }else if(i < max2){
        max2 = i;
    }
}
```

Maybe this part of the code is the problem:

```
else
fh = sh;

fl = sh;
sl = sh;
sh = fl;
```

Since there are no brackets, the last 3 lines will always be executed, independently of whether the condition is met or not.

Comment: I appreciate your answer man but I am not allowed to use Array and Arraysort.

Comment: @Presmelito that's why i added the second option (might need some minor modifications depending upon your constraints)

Comment: @Presmelito All that means is that you might want to roll your own sorting code. A basic bubble-sort would be enough for something like this. That said, it's a good idea to include any such restrictions in the question itself.

Comment: @Presmelito I'll think about a way of solving this without arrays

Comment: @Premelito i think i've found the issue with your code (or atleast a part of it)

Comment: @Paul Where is it? haha

Comment: @Presmelito i've added it to my post. I only **think** it's an error, might be intended

Comment: I tried to renew my code but still i cant find the solution on how to get the second highest and second lowest without using min and max_value

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Num {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
    int fh = 0, sh = 0, sl = 0, fl = 0;
    int difference1 = 1;
    int difference2 = 1;
    boolean t1=false, t2=false;
    int temp = 0, temp1, temp2;
    int a = s.nextInt();//for first number
    fh = sh = sl = fl = a;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        int b;
        t2=false;
        t1=false;
        b = s.nextInt();
        if (b > fh) {
            sh=fh;
            fh = b;
            t1 = true;
        }
        if (b < fl) {
            sl=fl;
            fl = b;
            t2 = true;
        }
        if (t2 == false) {
            temp1 = b - fh;     
            if (temp1 < difference1) {
                difference1 = temp1;
                sl = b;
            }
        }
        if (t1 == false) {
             temp2 = b - fl;
            if (temp2 > difference2) {
                difference2 = temp2;
                sh = b;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("First lowest   :" + fl);
    System.out.println("Second lowest  :" + sl);
    System.out.println("Second highest :" + sh);
    System.out.println("First highest  :" + fh);

}
```

}

this code work
i try on this code 4 hours
i change my code plz delete comment blew

Comment: Although your answer is correct OP does not want to use arrays and sorting.

Comment: @Mustafasabir It's worth noting that this answer was posted *before* that restriction was added to the question

Comment: i soon change it @Mustafasabir

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use arrays and sorting, a slightly hardcoded solution will work for you. The basic idea is to parse over you inputs twice, and pass them through a hardcoded set of `if()` conditions to find the highest number. In the first step find the highest number and assign it a value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, so that in the second step when you inputs are passed through same set of `if()` conditions the first highest value is not into account and now the highest value determined will be the second highest value . Following is the working code for finding highest and second highest number. You can extend this for finding lowest and second lowest numbers.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
        int fh = 0, sh = 0, sl = 0, fl = 0;
        int a = s.nextInt();
        int b = s.nextInt();
        int c = s.nextInt();
        int d = s.nextInt();
        int e = s.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {

            if (a > b && a > c && a > d && a > e) {
                // a is highest
                if (i == 1) {
                    //for first iteration, since a is highest store its value in fh and assing it value Integer.MIN_VALUE
                    fh = a;
                    a = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                   //for second iteration, now highest number will be the second highest so store it in sh. Similar for all other inputs.
                    sh = a;
                    continue;
                }
            } else if (b > c && b > d && b > e) {
                // b is highest
                if (i == 1) {
                    fh = b;
                    b = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    sh = b;
                    continue;
                }

            } else if (c > d && c > e) {
                // c is highest
                if (i == 1) {
                    fh = c;
                    c = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    sh = c;
                    continue;
                }

            } else if (d > e) {
                // d is highest
                if (i == 1) {
                    fh = d;
                    d = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    sh = d;
                    continue;
                }

            } else {
                // e is highest
                if (i == 1) {
                    fh = e;
                    e = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                    continue;
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    sh = e;
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }
        s.close();
        System.out.println("First highest is:- " + fh);
        System.out.println("Second highest is:- " + sh);
    }

}
```